# How to catch wcf service thrown exception at client side

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Inside my Form_Load `background_worker_DoWork` is started where I'm using wcf service call to get countAllBooksValue. At service I'm throwing Fault exception where that exception should be catched by the client, but it doesn't.

client side

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int countAllBooks = BookAgent.CountAllBooks();
                e.Result = countAllBooks;
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                             
            }            
        }
```

service side

```
public int CountAllBooks()
{
   throw new FaultException("Something bad happened!");
}
```

Question is: Why this FaultException is not catched by the client?

Comment: BackgroundWorker_DoWork is not UI thread, I actually think it might be catched, just not displayed - have you tried debugging ?

Comment: just tried debugging, catch block is not hitted at all, exception is thrown at service side and is not dispatched back to the client

Comment: Have you added the `FaultContract` attribute to your contract?

Comment: I added on service side inside configuration file <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

Comment: no, you need to add `FaultContract` onto the method in your interface. You will also need to update the service in your client so that it knows to expect it.

Comment: Or maybe not. I just created a new WCF service and set it up like you. It seemed to pass the exception down just fine.

Comment: I dont get it how. You using background worker as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults property:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```